# How to fix Stripe Error: Network error [errno 77]: error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: php, ssl, stripe-payments, tls1.2

I am attempting to use Stripe on my site but am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error:
    Uncaught Stripe\Error\ApiConnection: Unexpected error communicating with Stripe. If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com.
    (Network error [errno 77]: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: CApath: /etc/ssl/certs) in /var/www/html/assets/vendor/stripe/lib/HttpClient/CurlClient.php:284
Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/html/assets/vendor/stripe/lib/HttpClient/CurlClient.php(241): Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient->handleCurlError('https://api.str...', 77, 'error setting c...', 0) 
    #1 /var/www/html/assets/vendor/stripe/lib/HttpClient/CurlClient.php(203): Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient->executeRequestWithRetries(Array, 'https://api.str...') 
    #2 /var/www/html/assets/vendor/stripe/lib/ApiRequestor.php(364): Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient->request('post', 'https://api.str...', Array, Array, false) 
    #3 /var/www/html/assets/vendor/stripe/lib/ApiRequestor.php(96): Stripe\ApiRequestor->_requestRaw('post', '/v1/charges', Array, Array)
    #4 /var/www/html/assets/vendor/stripe/lib/ApiOperations/Request.php(5 in /var/www/html/assets/vendor/stripe/lib/HttpClient/CurlClient.php on line 284
```

I recently created a new VM on Google Compute Engine using the one-click LAMP deployment.  I also used Lets Encrypt to allow for https.  Further, I have downloaded the latest cacert.pem file and placed it in the `/etc/ssl/certs` folder.

The certs folder has the following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     20480 Apr  5 14:31 certs
```

The file has the following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 219596 Apr  5 14:29 cacert.pem
```

I also edited the `php.ini` file to point the `curl.cainfo` and `openssl.cafile` to the pem file and restarted Apache.

In looking at Stripe's site, it mentioned that TLS 1.2 is now required.  I have confirmed that my site is using it.  But some sample test code on Stripe's site seems to indicate that it's not seeing TLS 1.2.

According to ssllabs.com, my site is recognized as having the TLS 1.2 protocol.

The Stripe sample code that I added to my site to validate is:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");
    try {
        \Stripe\Charge::all();
        echo "TLS 1.2 supported, no action required.";
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
        echo "TLS 1.2 is not supported. You will need to upgrade your integration.";
    }
```

I also added the following for additional version information:

```
echo 'PHP version: ' . phpversion() . PHP_EOL . '<br/>';
    echo 'cURL version: ' . curl_version()['version'] . PHP_EOL . '<br/>';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo 'TLS version: ' . json_decode($response)->tls_version . PHP_EOL;
```

The result when I run it is:

```
============= Stripe Suggested Test Code ============
TLS 1.2 is not supported. You will need to upgrade your integration.
================================================
==================== Version Code ===================
PHP version: 7.0.33-0+deb9u3 
cURL version: 7.52.1 
TLS version: TLS 1.2 
================================================
```

At this point, I'm running out of ideas.  For full disclosure, I do most of my learning through Google searches and this site so any help at a hobby coder level would be appreciated.

Comment: running on localhost??? or LIVE? having SSL?

Comment: PHP 7.0 is end-of-life, you may want to look at an upgrade

Comment: I have same problem, because I installed libraries manually, and after fixing some dependencies by myself. Finally throw me this error. But refers in `\Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient.php` the method `handleCurlError($url, $errno, $message, $numRetries)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, looking at [the code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/HttpClient/CurlClient.php#L246) I see this:

```
class CurlClient implements ClientInterface
{
    public function request($method, $absUrl, $headers, $params, $hasFile)
    {
        ...
        $opts[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = Stripe::getCABundlePath();
        ...
    }
}
```

Which in turn, leads me to [this code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/Stripe.php#L137):

```
class Stripe
{
    // @var string Path to the CA bundle used to verify SSL certificates
    public static $caBundlePath = null;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    private static function getDefaultCABundlePath()
    {
        return realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../data/ca-certificates.crt');
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getCABundlePath()
    {
        return self::$caBundlePath ?: self::getDefaultCABundlePath();
    }
    /**
     * @param string $caBundlePath
     */
    public static function setCABundlePath($caBundlePath)
    {
        self::$caBundlePath = $caBundlePath;
    }
}
```

Which makes it look like Stripe doesn't want to use the system CA path for some reason. So you can:

- use `Stripe::setCABundlePath()` to point to the system CA bundle

or

- ensure the CA bundle at `data/ca-certificates.crt` (which is shipped with Stripe) is present and has appropriate permissions.

Comment: Yep. https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#configuring-ca-bundles Usually the best option is to make sure to include that `data/` directory when installing the library.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the help!  I was struggling with this for a couple weeks.  While the answers did not directly fix the problem, it shed light on the fact that I was apparently using an older version of the code which did not have reference to the ca-certificates file in the data directory [in fact there was no data directory].

After getting the latest from Github using Composer and cleaning up where my autoload was pointed, it is working again.  Thanks again!

Comment: `use Stripe::setCABundlePath() to point to the system CA bundle` can you explain how to do that?

Comment: Presumably something like `Stripe::setCABundlePath("/path/to/your/system/CA/bundle")` @vincentthorpe

Comment: On RHEL systems the system bundle is at `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`. No idea about others.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error message. I solved it by reinstalling the Stripe library. The root cause was missing or corrupt /data directory.

A link to instructions for installing/reinstalling the library can be found [here](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries).